# Quicksort doesnt work in some cases

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

As I was testing my quicksort I noticed another problem. Sometimes it arranges the array in alphabetical order and sometimes it does not. For example if I have `p, o, j, l` as my array it sorts it to `j, o, l, p` which is wrong because `l` should be before `o` However if I add `a` to the array it sorts to `a, j, l, o, p` which is correct. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
private ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
        if (lo < hi){
            int splitPoint = partition(ar, lo, hi);
            sort(ar, lo, splitPoint);
            sort(ar, splitPoint +1, hi);
        }
        return ar;
    }

    private int partition(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
        String pivot = ar.get(lo);
        lo--;
        hi++;
        while (true){
            lo++;
            hi--;
            while (lo<hi && ar.get(lo).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
                lo++;
            }
            while (hi>lo && ar.get(hi).compareTo(pivot) >= 0){
                hi--;
            }
            if (lo<hi){
                swap(ar, lo, hi);
            }else {
                return hi;
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> swap(ArrayList<String> ar, int a, int b){
        String temp = ar.get(a);
        ar.set(a, ar.get(b));
        ar.set(b, temp);
        return ar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are not changing the position of pivot element. You are just swapping hi with lo.

At the end, you should place the pivot at its correct position and then return it.

Comment: I keep comparing and swapping while `lo<hi`. Once that is false I return the `hi` which is the pivot in the correct position.

Comment: As far as I understand, initially lo == pivot. Hence 1st comparison of arr[lo] with arr[pivot] shall be zero, and lo will be incremented. pivot shall stay in its position.

Comment: Correct. But I am not moving the pivot I am just re-arranging the values. The weird thing is it works in all other cases besides this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a danger in the last iteration of your loop.

Suppose you had an array 2,1.

Your pivot is 2.

The lo index increases until it finds an element above the pivot of 1 or meets hi.
In this case it will meet hi and both lo and hi will be pointing to 1.

At this point your partition function returns and reports that the array has been partitioned into:

```
{2},{1}
```

But this is incorrect because 1 is < than the pivot so should have been in the first partition.

Perhaps when lo meets hi you should perform an extra test to see whether the element at hi should be included in the left or right partition?